# Copy Mongoose Document object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, api

I am working on a SaaS Application tracking system for Learning purposes. using ExpressJS and MongoDB.

I have a Schema for the applicant, where the applicant can build their profile and resume as below Schema.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const CandidateprofileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
candidate: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'candidate'
},
address: {
    type: String,
   
},
summery: {
    type: String,
   
},
linkend: {
    type: String,
   
},
skills: {
    type: [String]
},
experience: [
    {
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        company: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        location: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        from: {
            type: Date,
            required: true
        },
        to: {
            type: Date,
            
        },
        current: {
            type: Boolean
        },
        summery: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }

    }
],
education: [
    {
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        school: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        location: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        from: {
            type: Date,
            required: true
        },
        to: {
            type: Date,
            
        },
        current: {
            type: Boolean
        },
        type: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }

    }
],
training: [
    {
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        school: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        location: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        from: {
            type: Date,
            required: true
        },
        to: {
            type: Date,
            
        },
        details: {
            type: Boolean
        },
        type: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }

    }
],
certificate: [
    {
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        source: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        location: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            required: true
        },
        details: {
            type: String
        },
        certified: {
            type: Boolean
           
        }

    }
],
refrence: [
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        phone: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        company: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true
            
        },
        location: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        type: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }

    }
],
data: {
    type:Date,
    default:Date.now
}
}); 
module.exports = Candidateprofile = mongoose.model('Candidateprofile', CandidateprofileSchema);
```

Now I want to that when an applicant wants to apply for a specific job, I want the same user-filled profile should be copied to another MongoDB documents, where the user should not be able to modify that after he applied for the job. below is the return JSON for the applicant profile

```
{
"skills": [],
"_id": "5ff1f0aba9702d0baca6d03d",
"candidate": {
    "_id": "5ff09fc72cb32297d42b390c",
    "name": "nazir",
    "lastname": "noori",
    "email": "nazir@yahoo.com",
    "mobile": 7984545
},
"address": "2nd street",
"summery": "Hello World, I am developer",
"linkend": "https://linkend.com/nazir",
"experience": [
    {
        "_id": "5ff2add0628072523415f5e8",
        "title": "Admin Assistant",
        "company": "ABC",
        "location": "abc, xyz",
        "from": "2012-01-31T19:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2016-01-01T19:30:00.000Z",
        "summery": "I have been working as an office Assistant"
    }
],
"education": [
    {
        "_id": "5ff2e1feeb5e17194cb2210c",
        "title": "MBA",
        "school": "zyx",
        "location": "XYZ, Xyz",
        "from": "2016-10-11T19:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2019-01-04T19:30:00.000Z",
        "type": "degree"
    }
],
"training": [
    {
        "_id": "5ff2e3e9374cf034fc38d97e",
        "title": "MBA",
        "school": "XYZ Uni",
        "location": "xyz, xyz",
        "from": "2016-10-11T19:30:00.000Z",
        "to": "2019-01-04T19:30:00.000Z",
        "type": "degree"
    }
],
"certificate": [
    {
        "_id": "5ff2e495d984588178335c24",
        "title": "MBA",
        "source": "uni",
        "location": "xyz, abc",
        "date": "2016-10-11T19:30:00.000Z",
        "details": "degree"
    }
],
"refrence": [
    {
        "_id": "5ff2e62dd984588178335c26",
        "name": "Ahmad",
        "email": "me@me.com",
        "phone": "07888877",
        "company": "Abc",
        "title": "CEO",
        "location": "delhi",
        "type": "academic"
    }
],
"data": "2021-01-03T16:28:27.099Z",
"__v": 7
}
```

Could you kindly please suggest to me the best method to solve this issue and send a copy of applicant profile for the job, where the employer can review it and still the applicant has access to his/her profile

Comment: What I would try is to create `applicants` field in the job scheme as an array of ObjectIds, and when a user applies for that job, his/her id is added to the the `applicants` field of that job. Then you can use these ids for each job to allow the poster to view the profiles of the corresponding Ids, without actually storing the profile itself in the job schema.

Comment: BackMath, thank you, that is one option that I am thinking of, but the issue is that the user can update and modify his/her profile after the application submission, which is not good, I am looking for a solution that applicant should not apple to modify his application and should be able to apply for other job and update his profile